# How set radiobox checked by clickin on a <li> tag which contains this radiobox

Tags: javascript, html, css

[how do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRhg3.png)

How I can by clicking on `<li>` tag set radiobox checked

Check codepen its beetter https://codepen.io/Nicitaa/pen/dyqaKGY

Comment: Please post your code as text in the question.

Comment: Hmm it looks like your question consist mostly of code -add some details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use some JavaScript to add an event listener to the li element. When the li element is clicked, the event listener will access the radio button and set its checked attribute to true.

Try this:

```
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

listItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const radio = item.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');
    radio.checked = true;
  });
});
```

Comment: I searched it almost whole day yesterday - you save me so much time - thank you!

Comment: @Nevazno_html_css_js_3 No problem mate. Good luck with your project!